# how to use casauthentication.singlesignout without displaying the default CAS logout page

Tags: asp.net, cas

Our  .Net application uses CAS for single sign in. 
For single signout the method CasAuthentication.SingleSignOut(); signs out from the application but displays the default CAS logout page.

Is there a way to not dispaly the CAS logout page instead redirect to the logout page of our
Application website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to this:
For Single Sign out in .net in web.config add a key under appsettings named say "CAsUrl":
The value would be the CAS server url with service parmaeter pointing to the url you want to redirect after logout. 
Use this key in your application where you redirect after log out.

This would perform single sign out and redirect your application to the desired page and not the CAS logout page.